# Generate unique string in Kusto - Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, guid, azure-data-explorer, kql

How can we generate a unique string in Kusto? For example, it could be equivalent to Guid.NewGuid method in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. The function is [new_guid()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/newguidfunction).